# JAVA: Getting pause in application when Log file is going to roll over

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, wildfly-9

I am using wildfly 9 and slf4j(slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar)/log4j(log4j-1.2.17.jar).
I am getting a pause in the application when the file is going to roll-over.

My logging configuration in standalone.xml is below:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
        <level name="INFO" />
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN" />
        </formatter>
    </console-handler>
    <size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="PATTERN" />
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log" />
        <rotate-size value="30m" />
        <max-backup-index value="10000" />
        <append value="true" />
    </size-rotating-file-handler>
    <size-rotating-file-handler name="APPLICATION" autoflush="true">
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n" />
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="application.log" />
        <rotate-size value="30m" />
        <max-backup-index value="10000" />
        <append value="true" />
    </size-rotating-file-handler>
    <logger category="com.company" use-parent-handlers="true">
        <level name="INFO" />
        <handlers>
            <handler name="APPLICATION" />
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <root-logger>
        <level name="INFO" />
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE" />
            <handler name="FILE" />
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
    <formatter name="PATTERN">
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n" />
    </formatter>
    <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n" />
    </formatter>
</subsystem>
```

Any suggestion/configuration for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple suggestion: reduce `max-backup-index` to a lower value.

`max-backup-index=10000` means that on rollover the logging framework has to:

- delete `server-9999.log`
- rename `server-9998.log` to `server-9999.log`
- rename `server-9997.log` to `server-9998.log`
- ...
- rename `server.log` to `server-1.log`

and only then it can create a new `server.log`

Comment: When I change the log level from debug to info, log file name sequence like
  application.log
  application.log.1
  application.log.96
  application.log.137
  application.log.204
  application.log.301
  application.log.302
  application.log.303
  application.log.304
  application.log.305
  application.log.306
  application.log.697
  application.log.902
  application.log.903
  I observed that All log files renamed multiple times when current log file is going to roll over.
  Note: some times All log files renamed once when the rollover.

Comment: My problem is resolved after the <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"/> added and remove the <max-backup-index value="10000" />. And issue replicated when log level change from debug to info.